# Из географических координат в локальные

Tags: c#, google-maps-api, математика, геолокация, gps

***Описание:***

Есть координаты объектов в формате возвращённым Google Api. То есть широта, долгота и т.п.

Например у меня 3 объекта, берём объект (1) его локальные координаты становятся [0,0]. Объект (2) находится на 5 метров на север и 2 метра на восток относительно объекта (1), его координаты должны стать [5,2]. Объект номер (3) находится на 75 метров на юг и на 35 метров на запад, его координаты должны стать [-75, -35].

***Вопрос:***

Как перевести объекты в локальную систему координат зная их широту и долготу, пожалуйста помогите?

***Видимые решения:***

- Появилась мысль получить расстояние между объектами при помощи
  [следующего решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points-haversine-formula). (однако тут точность в км, как можно
  повысить до метров?) И после этого вычислить угол между
  географической координатой северного полюса, объекта (1) (который
  взят за [0,0] в локальных) и объекта (2) и уже зная дистанцию и
  угол рассчитать координату объекта (2) в локальных координатах. ***Будет ли искажение у угла,
  если я применю подобные вычисления?*** <strike>Земля же не квадратная</strike>.

P.S. Надо вычислять на телефоне, и таких вычислений будет до 50 шт за раз, а то и больше, желательно максимально оптимальное решение, но важна точность вплоть до 1 метра. ([Подобные вычисления на телефоне вызывают у меня опасения](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5))

P.P.S. Можете пожалуйста предоставить код на C# решения данного вопроса?

P.P.P.S. По идеи это всё похоже на систему где объект (1) - это человек, и требуется рассчитать в метрах положение объектов в локальных координатах (метрах). Однако я не смог найти, как это реализовано в gps навигаторах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точность позиционирования определяется точностью координат. Если Google возвращает тебе километры, значит будут километры. Возвращает метры - будут метры.

Да, разумеется, искажения будут. Прочитай про [проекции координат на плоскость](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F). Выбирай что тебе больше нравится - равноугольные, равновеликие или какие-нибудь ещё.

После того, как ты переведёшь географические координаты в координаты на плоскости, вычесть y/x одного объекта из другого для тебя не составит труда.

Пока чисел меньше 1 000 000 ты можешь использовать любое решение, потерь скорости ты не заметишь, больше потратишь на отображение.

Есть [готовое решение](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) на все случаи жизни, не обязательно изобретать собственный велосипед.